# How to make the chosen substring as a link and bold?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<%
int amountOfTags = 0;
string text = "hi @dude im @cool kay";
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < text.Length; a++)
{
    if (text.Substring(a, 1) == "@")
    {
        amountOfTags++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (text.Substring(i, 1) == "@")
    {
        number1 = i;
    }
    if (text.Substring(i, 1) == " " && number1 > number2)
    {
        number2 = i;
    }
    int number3 = number2 - number1;
    if (number2 - number1 < 13 && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0 && number2 > number1 && number2 == i && amountOfTags != -1)
    {
        if (text.Substring(number1 + 1, number3) != ", ")
        {
            Response.Write(text.Substring(number1 + 1, number3 - 1));
            amountOfTags--;
        }
    }
}
%>
```

Ok so this code takes a text for example "hi @dude im @cool kay" in ASP.NET and returns the text after the @, so the code will return me 'dude' and 'cool'
Now my question is, how to make the text it returns me from the substring to become a link and bold? (Like adding to that specific text an element).

Is it possible with ASP.NET or JS?

Comment: What would the href attribute (and any other attributes) of the link be?

Comment: I'm making a forum so I will link it to a user profile by the name with the values I already have in the page, for now a # will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of all of that confusing substring logic. You could reduce the logic to a single line *and* include your desired anchor wrapper:

```
<% string text = "hi @dude im @cool kay"; %>
<%= Regex.Replace(text, @"@([\S]+)", @"<a href=""#""><b>$1</b></a>") %>
```

Note: I have included `<b>` tags for simplicity, but I would recommend removing them and using CSS to make the link bold.

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot! Its working like charm, sad that there so many features I do not know in coding.